# SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider (and others)

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

I have an app set to open files via mimetype in AndroidManifest. Users can use Gmail, web browsers, file explorers, etc on these types of files and use "Share to" > "My app"

Personally, I have tested this on a range of devices and Android OS systems and never had an issue. According to Crashlytics, this particular crash is rare-but-not-rare-enough.

---

**Crash 1:**

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord{ce39380 24006:org.app/u0a1254} (pid=24006, uid=11254) that is not exported from UID 10055
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1954)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1900)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4800)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6750)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2821)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1820)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:750)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:716)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:667)
```

**Crash 2:**

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/749 from pid=5444, uid=10148 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderProxy.java:423)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:951)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:887)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:843)
```

**Crash 3:**

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{f485356 16849:org.app/u0a314} (pid=16849, uid=10314) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5308)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6780)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2769)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2117)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:928)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
```

**(There's more, but you get the idea)**

---

**But, why does this not happen on my devices or the majority of user's devices? I have no control over the sending of the Intent, only receiving it via `onNewIntent()` where I immediately do:**

```
if (intent == null) {
    return;
}

final Uri data = intent.getData();
if (data == null) {
    return;
}

String uriString = data.toString();
File intentFile = new File(uriString);
String filename = null;

if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        // CRASH OCCURS HERE: VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(data, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
} else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
    filename = intentFile.getName();
}
```

Comment: Are they providers you have on your devices too? `cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)` You are not checking if this returns -1 and calling cusor.getString() on it.

Comment: Further the apps that activate your apps can do it wrong for instance by not setting a grand read permission flag. Dont let your app crash. Catch that exception and display a Toast to the user when it happens.

Comment: `File intentFile = new File(uriString);` You should put that in that else block. And remove "file://" from uriString before you call new File(uriString). Well .. if you want a valid File instance. For only getting the name it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks yeah that's the "fix" I've implemented just now, to catch the exception. Else I can't see any other solution. I assume `opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider` is Chrome, which I have and have tried on various Android OS versions - works fine. Very odd.